# Rails: unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This used to work when I had rails 3.0.8. After hearing about some security issues with ActiveRecord I decided to update everything and this got broken. Let me know if you need anymore info.

error:

```
unknown attribute: gene_family_id
```

app/views/gene_families/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for( [@gene_family, @gene_family.cvits.build], :html => {:onsubmit => "return ray.ajax()" }) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

config/routes.yml

```
LisCvit::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :cvits, :path => 'cvit' do
          get 'new' , :on => :collection
  end
  resources :gene_families do
    resources :cvits
    collection do
      post 'blast'
      get 'search'
    end     
  end
  root :to => "cvits#error"
end
```

Full Trace:

```
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in `assign_attributes'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:235:in `build_record'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:500:in `initialize'
app/models/cvit.rb:6:in `initialize'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:183:in `new'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:183:in `build_association'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:233:in `build_record'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:112:in `build'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `__send__'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `build'
app/views/gene_families/show.html.erb:102:in `_app_views_gene_families_show_html_erb___277042720_17231010160'
app/views/gene_families/show.html.erb:92:in `each'
app/views/gene_families/show.html.erb:92:in `_app_views_gene_families_show_html_erb___277042720_17231010160'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `send'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
ruby/1.8/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.12/lib/thinking_sphinx/action_controller.rb:12:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/gene_families_controller.rb:178:in `show'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1468902388__process_action__453433196__callbacks'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:206:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `action'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
ruby/1.8/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__397314981__call__4__callbacks'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Comment: what is the full stacktrace you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you updated to 3.2.3 or higher, this *might* be caused by the new default approach to enforce whitelisting of attributes for mass-assignment. See the beginning of the [release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/30/ann-rails-3-2-3-has-been-released/). It's hard to tell if this is the cause of your error though without seeing the actual code that raises it.

Comment: this only changes default settings, so it should only impact new applications, not mine. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: That's true, but if you didn't use `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` before, it will impact the behaviour of your app.

Comment: Wow, great job :) adding gene_family_id as an attr_protected in my Cvits model made everything work